# haproxy in docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, haproxy

I'm new to docker and haproxy.. I tried to follow the example from the official [docker hub repo](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/).

So, I have Dockerfile

```
FROM haproxy:1.5
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

and simple haproxy config (which I expect to redirect local calls to my EB instance)

```
global
  # daemon
  maxconn 256

defaults
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  default_backend servers

backend servers
  server server1 {my-app}.elasticbeanstalk.com:80 maxconn 32
```

Build and run

```
$ docker build .
$ docker run --rm d4598bcc293f
```

Container starts and stucks, Ctrl+C doen't stop it. "docker kill" helps only.

My EB resource is up and running

```
$ curl {my-app}.elasticbeanstalk.com/status
{
  "status": "OK"
}
```

But local calls fail

```
$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.104

$ curl 192.168.59.104/status
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.59.104 port 80: Connection refused
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thank you!

> UPDATE: I've found the problem with calls redirections. Wrong port
>   number in haproxy.cfg.
>
> But this problem still annoys me... Container starts and stucks,
>   Ctrl+C doen't stop it. "docker kill" helps only.

Comment: Can you explain the {my-app} syntax and help me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130238/using-haproxy-via-docker-gives-invalid-characters-for-a-local-volume-name

Comment: @SurenderThakran it is just a name of the AWS Beanstalk app.

Comment: ohk i thought you are somehow linking haproxy docker container to an extermal service from inside the container. :p

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to exit with control-c, do `docker run -i <image>`. The `-i` means to pass input to the containerized program, and if HAProxy gets a control-c then it will terminate which will stop the container.

HAProxy doesn't produce any output unless you run it in debug mode, so there's not really much point to running attached, though. You might have a better time with `docker run -d <image>`, which will detach from the container and let it run in the background. To stop it, use `docker kill`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! For some reason Ctrl-C doesn't work for me when I run haproxy container in "-i" mode. But works with other containers, though.