# Error response from daemon: (config) includes invalid characters for a local volume name

Tags: docker, haproxy

I have a running node server which listens on 3 different ports.
I have three different subdomains of a url pointing to port `80` of the server on which node is running/listening.

What I am trying to do is proxy pass a request from a sub-domain to its respective port using `haproxy`.

My node server is dockerized with the ports exposed on the host. I can hit them individually using the server's IP address on their port so they seem to be running fine.

My `haproxy` will also be running inside a docker container. I am completely new to `haproxy` though I am fairly confident with dockers. I wrote my haproxy configuration via onine articles and blogs but as soon as I start my docker container using:

```
docker run --name my-running-haproxy \
  -v ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro \
  haproxy:1.6.2
```

I get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: ./haproxy.cfg includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed

So I tried debugging by removing configuration options until I had a very minimalistic config:

### haproxy.cfg

```
global
    maxconn 256
    debug

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend default-server

backend default-server
    server s0 127.0.0.1:3000
```

But still I am getting the same error.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by using full path to my config file.

### Original

```
docker run --name my-running-haproxy \
  -v ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro \
  haproxy:1.6.2
```

### Fixed

```
docker run --name my-running-haproxy \
  -v /usr/local/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro \
  haproxy:1.6.2
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but in my case the problem was with the indentation in the .cfg file. Apparently space indentation worked instead of tab indentation.

Comment: I had the same problem. Your answer was the solution, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
```

Using relative path:

> Example: `./haproxy.cfg`
>
> Example: `./PATH/haproxy.cfg`
>
> Example hidden file: `./PATH/.haproxy.cfg`

```
  -v ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
```

Using absolute path:

> Example: `/haproxy.cfg`
>
> Example: `/PATH/haproxy.cfg`
>
> Example hidden file: `/PATH/.haproxy.cfg`
>
> Example: `$PWD/haproxy.cfg`

```
  -v /PATH/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
```